# using realloc to write on a new string?

Tags: c, duplicates, c-strings, realloc, function-definition

> remove_multiple takes one parameter (a C string), and remove duplicates. it has to return the dynamically allocated string in the heap.

I've tried to:

- create a new dynamically allocated pointer (s);
- if the current character (of str) is not equal to the next character, just copy that in s, after having reallocated (s).

the problem is that I still have this warning on the realloc: "C6308    'realloc' might return null pointer: assigning null pointer to 's', which is passed as an argument to 'realloc', will cause the original memory block to be leaked", and when I try to debug the program I got a message, it says that I was trying to write outside the allocated memory.

here's my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* remove_duplicates(const char* str) {
    char* s = malloc(sizeof(char)); 
    if (!s) {
        return NULL; 
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++) {
        
        
        if (str[i] != str[i + 1]) {
            s = realloc(s, 2 * sizeof(char));
            if (!s) {
                return NULL;
            }
            s[i] = str[i];
        }
    }

    return s; 
}



int main(void) {
    char str[] = "heyyyy"; 
    char* s = remove_duplicates(str); 
    printf("%s", s); 

    free(s); 
    return 0; 
}
```

error list:

- Warning   C6308   'realloc' might return null pointer: assigning null pointer to 's', which is passed as an argument to 'realloc', will cause the original memory block to be leaked.

Comment: The warning is quite specific. If you get return value `NULL` you cannot reach the old address any longer and cannot free it as you have overwritten the variable with the `NULL` value. You can use a `temp` variable instead and only assign to `s` if it is not `NULL`.

Comment: `realloc(s, 2 * sizeof(char));` You will never be able to store more than 2 characters. Is that intented? I don't see that you limit index `i` to maximum 1.

Comment: @Gerhardh, should I do it instead?   "int n = 2; " s = realloc(s, n * sizeof(char));", and then "n++"?

Comment: No, why would you assign `2`? You write to index `i`. That means you must allocate at least `i+1`  bytes.

Comment: If you want to remove duplicate characters, you also  must use 2 index variables. One for the source and one for the destination array.

Comment: Instead of `*s = *tmp`, you need `s = tmp`.  With small allocations, it will often be true that `s = tmp` is a no-op since they are already the same, so this error will bite you only sporadically (under memory pressure).  But there are still many other issues in your code.

Comment: You have asked a very nicely presented original question, however by editing one of the key points out of your original question the whole purpose of the post is now confused with something entirely different.   You should not edit suggestions in comments that address the problems back into your original post.  I suggest rolling the post back to its original content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters your approach is not good.

The function is inefficient because within it there are too many memory reallocations.

As for the messages then this

```
s = realloc(s, 2 * sizeof(char));
```

statement is unsafe because the function `realloc` can return a null pointer. In this case the address of the previously allocated memory will be lost that results in a memory leak.

You need to use an intermediate pointer that will be assigned with the value returned by `realloc`.

In this statement

```
s = realloc(s, 2 * sizeof(char));
```

there are always allocated 2 bytes of memory.

Also there is used an invalid index in the left hand side expression

```
s[i] = str[i];
^^^^
```

For the pointer `s` you need to support its one index not `i`.

What you need is at first to determine how many there are non-duplicated adjacent characters and then only one time allocate an array of the required size.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * remove_duplicates( const char *s ) 
{
    size_t n = 0;
    
    for ( const char *p = s; *p; )
    {
        ++n;
        while ( *++p && p[0] == p[-1] );
    }
    
    char *result = malloc( n + 1 );
    
    if ( result != NULL )
    {
        char *p = result;
        do
        {
            *p = *s;
            while ( *s++ && s[0] == s[-1] );            
        } while ( *p++ );
    }
    
    return result;
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *s = "1223334444";
    
    printf( "\"%s\"\n", s );
    
    char *p = remove_duplicates( s );
    
    if ( p )    printf( "\"%s\"\n", p );

    free( p );
}
```

The program output is

```
"1223334444"
"1234"
```

Answer (score 2):

You are normally not expected to realloc for each character. So the lazy way would be to initially allocate an array of the same size of the original array, and optionally try to shrink it in the end:

```
char* remove_duplicates(const char* str) {
    char* s = malloc(1 + strlen(str)); // only allocate once with original size
    if (!s) {
        return NULL;
    }
    // keep track or current position, size and previous character
    char c, old = 0, *curr = s;
    size_t n = 0;
    while ((c = *str++) != '\0') {
        // ignore duplicates
        if (c != old) {
            *curr++ = c;
            old = c;
            ++n;
        }
    }
    // add the terminating null
    *curr = '\0';
    // optional shrink attempt
    s = realloc(s, n +  1);
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `s = realloc(s, n +  1);` present the potential of a memory leak?

Comment: @ryyker: Yes it does, yet it is an idiomatic way. `realloc` is allowed to change nothing and return the original pointer (no problem then...). If it successfully allocates a new array, then it will free the original one. The memory leak only occurs if it fails to allocate the new array, but as memory allocation errors are generaly fatal, it does not really matter because the program is close to its end.

Comment: @chux I should never have used upper case here. Fixed